# function that returns a list [0,[x1],[x1,x2],[x1,x2,x3]...] where [x1,x2,x3....] is the original list

Tags: haskell

How can I make in Haskell a function that gets a list and return a list of lists in this way:

```
[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5....]

it should return :

[[0],[x1],[x1,x2],[x1,x2,x3],[x1,x2,x3,x4][x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]....]
```

without using ready function that do it in Haskell.

Comment: What have you tried?  What should the type of such a function be?  Have you looked at the `inits` function?

Comment: the type should be : [int]->[[int]] I think

Comment: You mean `[Int] -> [[Int]]`, types in Haskell have to start with a capital letter.  If you type that type into [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[Int]+-%3E+[[Int]]), the first result is the `inits` function, which does something very similar to what you want.  Can you use that function (or read it's source on Hackage) to figure out how to solve your problem?

Comment: I looked at the definition of inits :    
inits      :: [a] -> [[a]]   
inits []     = [[]]
inits (x:xs) = [[]] ++ map (x:) (inits xs)  
 . I know that map gets a function and a list.. what does map get in this definition?

Comment: `map` is being recursively called on `inits1 xs`, with the function `(x:)`.  This could also be written as `map (\rest -> x : rest) (inits1 xs)`, but the [operator section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator) is a lot shorter and cleaner.

Comment: I didn't realize that (x:) is a function. thanks :)

Comment: No problem!  If you reach a solution on your own, please remember to add it as an answer so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: The function `(x:)` takes a list and prepends `x` in front of it. E.g. `(1:) [2,3,4] = [1,2,3,4]`. The `map (x:) (inits xs)` fragment reads as: take the `inits` of `xs`, which is a list of lists of `Int`, and prepend `x` to each of these lists. E.g. `map (1:) [[2],[2,3]] = [[1,2],[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: The `(x:)` syntax is called a section, and can be used with any binary operator. E.g. `(2+)` is "add 2", `(4*)` is "multiply by 4", etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the empty list `[]` at the start, not `[0]`.

In which case, it's just `inits`.

Here's it's definition if you want to write it yourself:

```
inits xs =  [] : case xs of []      -> []
                            x : xs' -> map (x :) (inits xs')
```

Comment: OP: next time, you can find it by just [searching the type in Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BInt%5D-%3E%5B%5BInt%5D%5D). `inits` is actually the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
    import System.IO 

    transform :: [Int] -> [[Int]] 
    transform list = trans 0  
            where trans n = case (length list) >= n of 
                            True -> (take n list):( trans (n+1) ) 
                            False -> [] 
    main = do 
            print . show $ transform [1..7]
```

Output:

```
$> ./transform
"[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]"
```

---

**Edit:** To work with Infinite Lists

```
    transform :: [a] -> [[a]]                                                    
    transform list = trans 0 []                                                  
            where                                                                
            trans :: a ->  [a]  -> [[a]]                                         
            trans n last = case last == list of                                  
                            False -> [take n list]++(trans (n+1) $ take n list)  
                            True -> []
```

Comment: @SassaNF eventually learnt that I shouldn't be in Haskell if were to use length.

Comment: ``transform list = [] : zipWith ($) (map take [1..]) (map (const list) list) = [] : zipWith const (map (`take` list) [1..]) list``.

Comment: BTW your edited version shouldn't typecheck: because you compare `last == list`, its type is `transform :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]`. Notice the context. You could write `notShorter n xs | n >=0 = n==0 || not (null xs) && notShorter (n-1) (tail xs)` and call `notShorter n list` instead (no need for `last` then). -- also, with Control.Applicative, ``transform list = [] : zipWith ($) (take <$> [1..]) (list <$ list) = [] : getZipList (ZipList ((`take` list) <$> [1..]) <* ZipList list)``.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the empty list at the start:

```
prefixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
prefixes ls = map (\x -> take x ls) [0..(length ls)]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829897/function-that-returns-a-list-0-x1-x1-x2-x1-x2-x3-where-x1-x2-x3#comment36674808_23834904